# How to avoid having to add '\n' with sed(1)

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I want to insert a big chunk of code using a bash script.

This is how I got it to work using sed(1);

```
$ sed "/);/i\
\ \ \ \ 'doctrine' => array(\n\
        'driver' => array(\n\
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(\n\
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',\n\
                'cache' => 'array',\n\
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '\../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')\n\
            ),\n\
            'orm_default' => array(\n\
                'drivers' => array(\n\
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'\n\
                )\n\
            )\n\
        )\n\
    ),\n
" config/autoload/local.php;
```

Note: I had to add \n and \ at the end of each line in order to make it work.

Is there a way to "not" have to do that? To insert plain text? Perhaps a different command?

**Edit: my question is how to insert the text without having to add all the backslashes and newlines.**

This is the text I need to insert:

> ```
> 'doctrine' => array(
>     'driver' => array(
>         __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
>             'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
>             'cache' => 'array',
>             'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
>         ),
>         'orm_default' => array(
>             'drivers' => array(
>                 __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
>             )
>         )
>     )
> )
> ```

Comment: your script simply insert the code chunk without any special search or replace command, why sed?

Comment: pretty sure you don't need the `\n` in the `\n\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
sed '/);/i\
'doctrine' => array(\
    'driver' => array(\
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(\
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',\
            'cache' => 'array',\
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')\
        ),\
        'orm_default' => array(\
            'drivers' => array(\
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'\
            )\
        )\
    )\
)' file.php
```

If you're trying to insert a file, try:

```
sed '/);/ { 
    h
    r replacement.txt
    g
    N
}' file.php
```

Comment: But I need to insert it before the match. Not replace the line. I do like the file method though, but I need to insert before and with a file.

Comment: @Tool, sorry I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I have updated my answer. What do you think?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to add all the backslashes at the end of the line. Do you think that might be possible?

Comment: @Tool: Unfortunately, I think the backslashes at the end of each of the replacement lines are necessary. Fortunately, they're a cinch to add: `sed -i "s/$/\\\/" replacement.txt`

Comment: @Tool: Please see the edit I've made. It works if the pattern you're searching for doesn't occur on the last line of input. I'll get around to fixing this later tonight. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat << 'EOF' >> config/autoload/local.php
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
EOF
```

To use the lines with sed, you could print into a variable with `read`:

```
read -d '' multiLineString <<"EOF"
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
EOF
```

Then use `$multiLineString` with `sed`.

Comment: How do I incorporate this into the sed(1) context?

Comment: Getting a "sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown command: `''" with this method.

Comment: The second one won't work because if you're inserting multiple lines in sed, you need to terminate each line (except the last one) with backslash, or else you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `sed`, one way (without using backslash at the end of each line) is to save it to a temporary file, e.g.

```
cat >tempfile <<'EOF'
  code here...
EOF
```

then use the `r` (read) command in `sed`

```
sed '/);/ r tempfile' config/autoload/local.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >insert_file
    'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)

!
sed '/);/e cat insert_file' file.php
```